# How can i input the correct Timestamp corresponding to the time, when the data was retrieved in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, datetime, sqldatetime

I am modifying a code snippet from a udemy course, to fit my goal. My goal - > being able to store the timestamps in a sqlite3 database corresponding to the actual time the data was retrieved.
The original code excerpt to update the database from the RaspberryPiFullStack_Raspbian github repository is given below;

```
def log_values(sensor_id, temp, hum):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('/var/www/lab_app/lab_app.db')  #It is important to provide an
                                 #absolute path to the database
                                 #file, otherwise Cron won't be
                                 #able to find it!
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO temperatures values(datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime'),
         (?), (?))""", (sensor_id,temp))
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO humidities values(datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime'),
         (?), (?))""", (sensor_id,hum))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.AM2302, 17)
temperature = temperature * 9/5.0 + 32
```

As you can see, when the log_values function is called, only the instantaneous temperature and humidity value from the sensor, with the sqlite datetime function to timestamp when the reading was taken.

However, I have to process the values before i input them into the database. i have a function called "getAEEG(raw_data)", that accepts a list of raw data and returns a list of processed data. This function works fine independently. I have created an empty list for the temperature, humidity, and time that runs approximately for 10 seconds to store data onto the list. At the end of 10 seconds, i wish to store the values onto the database, with a for loop that iterates throughout the list to put them into the database. I have tried multiple iterations with no success, This is my first attempt coding in python and attempting to do projects with servers and databases, so i am reaching out to seek help diagnosing what's wrong with my code below.

```
t_data = []
ch1_data = []
ch2_data = []
ch1_aeeg = []
ch2_aeeg = []

def log_values(time_now,sensor_id, temp, hum):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('/var/www/lab_app/lab_app.db')  #It is important to provide an
                                 #absolute path to the database
                                 #file, otherwise Cron won't be
                                 #able to find it!
    # For the time-related code (record timestamps and time-date calculations) to work 
    # correctly, it is important to ensure that your Raspberry Pi is set to UTC.
    # This is done by default!
    # In general, servers are assumed to be in UTC.
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO temperatures values((?),
         (?), (?))""", (time_now,sensor_id,temp))
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO humidities values((?),
         (?), (?))""", (time_now,sensor_id,hum))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
def getAEEG(raw_eeg):
    fs = 240.0 #typical sampling frequency for EEG
    f0 = 60.0 #freq to remove by notch
    Q = 30.0 #quality factor
    #notch filter to remove 60 Hz
    b_n, a_n = signal.iirnotch(f0/(fs/2), Q)
    notch_eeg = signal.lfilter(b_n, a_n, raw_eeg)    
    #rectify eeg signal and convert V to uV
    rectify_eeg = abs(notch_eeg)
    #envelope filtered signal with low-pass 5th order Butterworth filter
    b,a = signal.butter(5, 0.021)
    envelope_eeg = signal.filtfilt(b,a, rectify_eeg)
    #aeeg output with added gain of 1.631
    aeeg_output = 1.631*(envelope_eeg)
    return aeeg_output

# setting up the 10 second condition for the while loop
time_now_counter = datetime.datetime.now()
tdelta = timedelta(seconds = +10)
time_stop = time_now_counter + tdelta

while time_now_counter < time_stop:
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    t_data.append(time_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    ch1_data.append(chan.voltage)
    ch2_data.append(random.randint(1,100))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    time_now_counter = datetime.datetime.now()
    
ch1_aeeg = getAEEG(ch1_data)
ch2_aeeg = getAEEG(ch2_data)

for x in range(len(ch1_aeeg)):
    time_now = t_data[x]
    temperature = ch1_aeeg[x]
    humidity = ch2_aeeg[x]
    log_values(time_now,"1", temperature, humidity)
```

P.S. i also have scheduled a cron job, that is supposed to run the script every 15 seconds, since i thought that between two consecutive scheduled runs, the script will have to run for 10 seconds to get enough data with the remaing 5 seconds being buffer time.

is my rationale valid?

Comment: it just never logs the values onto the database. it only ever works and updates the database with the first code snippet, when i call the function log_values("1", temp, hum) ; and pass temp and hum as solo input parameters (instead of it being part of a list as illustrated in the second code snippet)

Comment: the indentation in your function `log_values` is off. Was that just a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: yes, my mistake!

Comment: @snakecharmerb does the "curs.execute" line in the log_values function in both the cases do the same thing? is there a difference between doing datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime')     vs   manually inputting datetime from a list with a for loop?

Comment: `log_values` is being called in a loop, so the most likely explanation is that `len(ch1_aeeg)` is zero.